# Docker Kubernetes cluster error Request had insufficient authentication scopes on Google Cloud

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to run a Kubernetes cluster on Google cloud. I am using the below link - http://kubernetes.io/docs/hellonode/

When I execute the below command - gcloud container clusters get-credentials hello-world

I get an error Request had insufficient authentication scopes

What is the possible solution to this problem?

Comment: Looks like you're running the ```gcloud container clusters get-credentials hello-world``` from Google Compute Engine instance?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 3):

The Container Engine API requires the `cloud-platform` [OAuth2 Scope](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#oauth-scopes) for authentication. If you are running these commands from a Google Compute Engine instance, you'll need to create the instance with that authentication scope:

- With the gcloud CLI, add `--scopes=cloud-platform` to your `gcloud compute instances create` command.
- In the Developer Console UI, select "Allow full access to all Cloud APIs" on the "Create an Instance" page.